# Weird linux problem: user is in www-data group in /etc/groups but groups command doesn't show him

Tags: linux, user-accounts

I've come into something strange.

I just added a user to the *www-data* group, the user appears in both `/etc/group` and `/etc/group-`, however when I use the `groups` or `id` commands the group isn't listed; and the user can't chgrp a file into *www-data*.

What could be the problem?
I'm using a Debian testing machine, never had this kind of problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group membership is only processed on login. You can either:

- re-login to pick up the new group
- use `newgrp www-data` to run a new shell with gid set to `www-data`

Comment: Thanks a lot; I was closing and opening a new terminal, I though that was enough.

Comment: Nope, the new terminal is just inheriting the uid/gids from what started it (probably your window manager)

Comment: I did not see the new groups until I did a `su - $USER`.  `login` did not work either.