# genet group doesn't show the user in the ldap directory

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am running openldap2-2.4.26-0.24.36 server.

ON the machine, I use ldapmodify to add a user to the group.

Query with ldapsearch can show the correct user being added.

However getent group $the_group doesn't show the group having that member.

Can anyone suggest what's the possible reason?

[update]:
This [article](https://superuser.com/questions/101863/weird-linux-problem-user-is-in-www-data-group-in-etc-groups-but-groups-command) suggest to log off and log in.

I logged off and back in to the ldapserver, it still doesn't show.
However, when I logged in to a different server , it shows the user.